# dplyr summarise function rounding the means

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics, aggregate

I have this MRE data frame in R:

```
     set.seed(42)

     height <- runif(12, min = 6, max = 18)

     line <- rep(1:2, each = 6)
    
    treatment <- rep(1:2, times = 6)
    
    block <- rep(1:2, each = 6)
    
    mydata <- data.frame(line, block, treatment, height)
    
    mydata$line <- as.factor(mydata$line)
    mydata$block <- as.factor(mydata$block)
    mydata$treatment <- as.factor(mydata$treatment)
```

I want to summarise it. First, using aggregate:

```
newdata <- aggregate(height ~ line + block + treatment, 
                 data = mydata, 
                 FUN = mean)
```

And its output is:

```
    > newdata
  line block treatment   height
1    1     1         1 13.37076
2    2     2         1 13.40529
3    1     1         2 15.14648
4    2     2         2 12.23537
```

When using dplyr:

```
new_data <- mydata %>%
  group_by(line, block, treatment, .groups = 'keep') %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE))
```

And my output is:

```
    > new_data
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   line, block, treatment [4]
  line  block treatment .groups  mean
  <fct> <fct> <fct>     <chr>   <dbl>
1 1     1     1         keep     13.4
2 1     1     2         keep     15.1
3 2     2     1         keep     13.4
4 2     2     2         keep     12.2
```

My question is, why does dplyr round the mean? How can I stop it from doing so? I've inserted

```
na.rm = TRUE
```

to try and fix this after it was suggested to me, but it still didn't work.

TIA!